# Storing same data into storage.sync, Chrome uses much more quota than Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions, google-chrome-storage, webextension-storage

### **Background**

I'm working on [**a browser addon (webextension API)**](https://github.com/garywill/bigSearch), which is cross-browser (Firefox & Chromium/Chrome/Blink).

I need to use `browser.storage.sync` (`chrome.storage.sync` on Chrome) to storage so that data can be synced.

`storage.sync` limits storage size (128kB), so I've tried these JS compressing library:

- [lzutf8](https://github.com/rotemdan/lzutf8.js) (LZ77 algorithm)
- [lz-string](https://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/lz-string/index.html) (LZW algorithm)

(`lzutf8` compression results a smaller size)

### **Using the compress library**

Above two both support `uint8Array` output, but when I tried storing `uint8Array` into `storage.sync` they got about 10 times bigger, obviously not really stored in `uint8` format.

Then I found compressing to string is the best way to store:

```
Y1 = LZUTF8.compress(input-data, {outputEncoding: "StorageBinaryString"});
```

```
Y2 = LZString.compressToUTF16(input-data)
```

( Both Y are UTF16 string )

### **Question**

Storing the compressed data Y (string) into Firefox (78) and Chromium (90), **the space it occupies in `storage.sync` different**:

- **in Firefox:** Bytes used = `Y.length`.
- **in Chromium:** Bytes used = about 2-3 times larger than `Y.length`. **WHY?**

(The space used can be seen by `storage.sync.getBytesInUse()`. Both Firefox and Chromium have limitation of same quata: 128k bytes)

I need some explaination. I can't find any doc about how (and what object type) data is stored in `storage.sync`. Also, I'll appriciate if there is better compressing and storaging (sync supported) solution.